# anything wrong with my vb code?

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6

As the topic, here is my code.
Can anyone please help me to figure what's wrong with these code, cuz it will show error when I run it.

```
Dim age As Integer
         age = CInt(lblResult.Text)
         Do While age ^ 2 - 1980 <> age
         age = age + 1
         lblResult.Text = "The solution is " & CStr(age) & " years old."
Loop
```

Comment: You'll need to be a little more specific. If you don't understand why, try emailing your doctor a picture of yourself with an email that says "I don't feel well. What's wrong?" and see if you get a reply back with a diagnosis and treatment.

Comment: at least tell us what line the error is on, and what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is a `StackOverflowException` because of an infinite loop, from these lines:

```
Do While age ^ 2 - 1980 <> age
     age = age + 1
     lblResult.Text = "The solution is " & CStr(age) & " years old."
Loop
```

Since you are modifying the right-hand comparison value of `age` in the loop itself and the condition for breaking the loop is when `age ^ 2 - 1980` equals `age`, then that condition will never happen.

Not sure what the logic of `age ^ 2 - 1980 <> age` is really supposed to be, but do one of the following:

1. Introduce a loop counter variable (i.e. `lcv`) that is used in the comparison for the `Do`.
2. Change the condition of the `Do` to be something besides not equal (`<>`), to greater than or less than. Again, this is hard to recommend because I honestly have no idea what the purpose of this loop actually is.

Finally, you do not need to use `CStr()` to cast an `Integer` to a `String`, just use the `ToString()` of the `Integer` variable, like this:

```
lblResult.Text = "The solution is " & age.ToString() & " years old."
```

OR

Use `String.Format()`, like this:

```
lblResult.Text = String.Format("The solution is {0} years old.", age)
```

Comment: Is that the same as 1980+age<>age^2 ?

Comment: @user2975680 - is what the same? This is your logic, what in the world is this `Do` loop supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The error probably comes from

```
age = CInt(lblResult.Text)
```

replace CInt() by Val() and it might run better

```
age = Val(lblResult.Text)
```

Like the others I am also puzzled by the logics of your loop:

You only stop the loop when : age ^ 2 - 1980 = age

**Some simple math solves this to be when age=45 (or when age =-44)**

Why dont you simply loop until age=45 ?

In your case it does work because your loop equation has an integer solution, but what if the answer would have been age=45.3 ? In that case your loop would have been endless